# How to select entity from ManyToMany relation with condition

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am wondering how can I fetch inner entity from my `@ManyToMany` relation with additional parameter. So let's say I do have `MOVIES`, `REVIEW`, `MOVIES_REVIEW` tables in database. And at the beginning in my code I would like to select only MOVIES which interest me.

My repository looks like that:

```
  @Query("SELECT a FROM MOVIES a LEFT JOIN a.reviewDocuments b WHERE b.review.star='5' AND b.author=(?1)")
  Set<Movies> findByAuthor(String author);
```

So here we are lazy selecting `Set` of movies, where review has 5 stars and author has given name.
But after it operation let's say I want to iterate over all movie and print all Reviews but with additional parameter.

So lets say here I would like to have review only with 5 stars. But what I am getting is obviously all reviews.

Can I somehow do it without writing new `repository` class for reviews? But even if I would need to create new repository I can access reviews if I am correct.

Entittis:

```
@Entity(name = "MOVIES")
@Table(name = "MOVIES")
public class Movies {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "MOVIE_KEY")
    private String movieKey;
    @Column(name = "TYPE_ANIMATED")
    private String typeAnim;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "MOVIES_REVIEWDOCUMENTS",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "MOVIE_KEY"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "DOCUMENT_KEY"))
    private List<ReviewDocuments> reviewDocuments;
}

@Entity(name = "REVIEWDOCUMENTS")
@Table(name = "REVIEWDOCUMENTS")
public class ReviewDocuments {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "OBJID")
    private Long objId;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "reviewDocuments")
    private Set<Movies> movies;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, your only and best option is to use a custom query in your Repository. Instead of using the `@Query` annotation, you can rely on Spring Data JPA Query Creation based on the method name. You can do that as follows in the Repository for `Movies` assuming you have `String star` as an attribute in `ReviewDocuments` entity:

```java
Set<Movies> findByAuthorAndReviewDocumentsStar(String author, String rating);
```